# Why game lagging?

Tags: steam, games, vulkan

I played in dota 2 at Windows perfectly, but at linux (Manjaro, Arch, Ubuntu, Linux mint and Fedora) it's lagging, fps dropping and frametime jumping + some issues with grass textures. Game on SSD (Filesystem: EXT4) Fedora at other SSD (Filesystem: BTRFS). My PC: CPU: i3-8100 GPU: AMD RX580 4GB RAM: 16GB

All updates installed.

I record video with mangohud.

[video](https://youtu.be/HQj58sSktv0)

Comment: Can you repro the issue with AMDPRO drivers?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Чтож, пытался я только что поставить про стек драйверов, но amdgpu-core не установился, ТК ядро не то, причем на сайте АМД нигде не сказано на счёт нужной версии ядра. Теперь система у меня не запускается , просто белый экран с грустным смайликом и надписью,что произошла ошибка. Я зашёл через другой TTY, удалил все пакеты, связанные с amdgpu-pro — не помогло, удалил все пакеты, связанные с amdgpu — тоже не помогло.